# data-* 属性は数値のみからなる属性名が利用できるか

Tags: html5

HTML5 では data-* 属性に

1. data- の後に1文字以上続くこと
2. XML-compatibleであること
3. ASCII大文字を含まないこと

の3つを要求しています

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes

`<div data-1="1"></div>` の data-1 属性は上記3つを全て満たしているので HTML valid だと思うのですが、認識に間違いないでしょうか？

Answer (score 8, accepted):

間違いありません。

規格上そう読めますし、[dataset の setter のアルゴリズム](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#dom-domstringmap-setitem)でも数字で始まる名前をエラーにしません。下記のコードは Chrome, Edge, Firefox, Safari で動作します。

```js
document.body.dataset['012'] = 'value';
alert(document.body.getAttribute('data-012'));
```

だたし、数字で始めるとドット形式のアクセスは不可能になります。

```
document.body.dataset.012 = 'value'; // SyntaxError
```